# disable submit button with jquery AjaxForm plugin

Tags: jquery, forms, button, double, submit

I am using the jquery Form plugin to submit my form via ajax.  It works great, however, I have come into one issue which I cannot solve.  While the form is submitting, I wish to disable the submit button.  This is because the ajax call takes a little while to load and I don't want users to think nothing is happening and click the submit again.  When the form is finished submitting, I would like to re-enable the submit button.  Here is my code which I have tried, however it doesn't work and prevents the form from submitting at all.

```
$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function () {
  $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#settings-form').ajaxForm(function() { 
    $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
    jAlert('Thank you', 'jquery basic alert box');
  }); 
}); 


<form action="settings.php" method="post" class="standard-form" id="settings-form">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" size="16" value="" class="password-entry" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php _e( 'Update'); ?>" id="submit" class="small button"/>
</form>
```

Comment: can you show your html markup ?

Comment: sure updated @NalinAggarwal

Comment: Is there any error or anything on console? Because there is no error in code which disable the button.

Comment: @NalinAggarwal no error.  The form just doesn't ever submit.  The button stays disabled and nothing ever happens